# Embed wiki content in a website

Tags: web, embed, wiki

I want to have a few of my webpages to be in wiki format. I tried using Moin moin, and embeded it on a webpage with html iframe tag. But it loads the entire wiki page with the header and footer. I want to embed just the wikicontent without the header, footer and the sidebar. For the website I use django frame work. Are there any wiki plugings that work well with the custom templates? Or are there any wiki apps which just output content/body part of a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is surely an easy way to do this. I suggest you ask in the MoinMoin forums.

With Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware, a page like:

- http://doc.tiki.org/Draw

Is visible in an iframe-friendly format using:

- http://doc.tiki.org/tiki-index_p.php?page=Draw

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dooWikis](http://doowikis.com) where you can embed just the wiki into your page so that it looks like your own.  You can also turn the "Edit" link on or off depending whether or not you want to make it look like a wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightweight [wiki-embedded](https://github.com/prototype-59/wiki-embedded) specially designed to be embedded inside webpages. It supports Markdown language, it is self-contained and does not require page reload while browsing and editing wiki.